# DAX Measures Running Totals in Power Pivot

Tags: dax, powerpivot, cumulative-sum

Hoping I can get some help on obtaining running total DAX measures for sales and sales % contribution. I've searched quite a few sites/resources and tried a few formulas but no luck with the usual SUMX, <=MAX filters.

I suspect this could be due to trying to get the running total on an aggregated part number level (PN column) while the data is also broken down by period. New to DAX and Power Pivot so any further explanations/feedback on what I'm doing wrong/can be improved would be very helpful. The running totals will be used in the end for a ABC classification. Calculations are in Power Pivot and not Power BI.

Links below to what I'm looking for + data structure + link to sample file with all of the DAX measures:

[What I need to achieve](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eRZQ1.png)

[Data structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5APEw.png)

[Sample file with all DAX Measures](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Qxnzpw47LdGEwQn4vY-VfmyD-ZtdGobR/edit?usp=share_link&ouid=113130596801483369843&rtpof=true&sd=true)

Adding in the various formulas I've tried here:

Test_CumulativeSales1

```
=VAR MaxSales = MAX(f_1a_3PS[Sales])
RETURN CALCULATE(SUM(f_1a_3PS[Sales]), f_1a_3PS[Sales] <= MaxSales, ALLEXCEPT(f_1a_3PS, f_1a_3PS[PN]))
```

Test_CumulativeSales2

```
SUMX(FILTER(ALLEXCEPT(f_1a_3PS, f_1a_3PS[PN]), f_1a_3PS[Sales] <= MAX(f_1a_3PS[Sales])), f_1a_3PS[Sales])
```

Test_CumulativeSales3

```
=VAR CurrentPN = IF(HASONEVALUE(f_1a_3PS[PN]), VALUES(f_1a_3PS[PN]))
RETURN CALCULATE(SUM(f_1a_3PS[Sales]), FILTER(ALL(f_1a_3PS), f_1a_3PS[PN] = CurrentPN && 
f_1a_3PS[Period] <= MAX(f_1a_3PS[Period])))
```

Test_Cumulative%

```
=VAR SalesPercent = DIVIDE(SUM(f_1a_3PS[Sales]), CALCULATE(SUM(f_1a_3PS[Sales]), ALL(f_1a_3PS)))
RETURN SUMX(FILTER(ALL(f_1a_3PS[Sales]),
    f_1a_3PS[Sales] <= f_1a_3PS[Sales]), SalesPercent)
```

Please let me know if more info/clarification is needed. Thanks.

Comment: You can only achieve this with DAX if you first dictate the *order* in which the cumulative total should be applied. Currently that order appears to be rather arbitrary, based solely on relative row position within the worksheet. Cumulative totals are typically based on dates, which makes sense. Here I am not sure what your logic is for determining the cumulative order: if I were to sort the PNs within your current Pivot Table, for example, would you wish to see a new set of cumulative totals, based on that order? If so, this will not be possible with DAX.

Comment: Hi @JosWoolley, thanks for taking the time to reply, my sort logic would be based on largest to smallest (in terms of sales volume) and a cumulative sum of that on the PN level. Would be able to share how this can be achieved?